# weighted tabulation values in matlab

Tags: matlab

in Matlab I'd like to weight the value **a**:

```
a=randi([1,8],10,1)
```

for weights in **b**:

```
f=randi([0,2000],10,1)
```

And then tabulate the table for weighted **a**:

I've tried, but It's wrong:

```
bsxfun(@times,a,b)
```

Could you please *help* me? Thanks in advance.

Cristiano

Comment: Your `f` should be `b`, I think. Are you just trying to do an [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), i.e., matrix multiplication: `a*b.'`? It's not clear how you're applying the weights or what you mean by "tabulate". An example with your expected output would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a matrix of all combinations of `a(i)*b(j)` for all `i` in `length(a)` and all `j` in `length(b)`, you need to transpose one of them in `bsxfun`:

```ml
res1 = bsxfun(@times, a', b);
res2 = bsxfun(@times, a, b');
```

These should give the results such that `res1' = res2` (the transpose of one is equal to the other).

Comment: thanks all for replies. I'm sorry about poor explanation of the problem. I think I've found a solution here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/300327